# Microsoft Graph API : Unknown Error trying to get Messages in a channel

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to get Messages from a Team Channel using Python. I'm using the beta endpoint since I know that this functionality is not available in the 1.0 version.

I have all the required permissions:

- Type: Application
- Permissions: `ChannelMessage.Read.All`, `Group.Read.All`, `Reports.Read.All`

We sent the form Microsoft requires to unlock the API's methods 2 weeks ago, and we had no feedback from them. Should we wait longer? Or the problem is something else?

I'm able to get all of the ID I need (`team_id` and `channel_id`), but when I try to get `/messages`:

```py
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + reporting_team_id + "/channels/" + test_channel_id + "/messages"
```

I get this Unknown Error:

```py
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6d6bc5b3-e340-4ea5-ac9b-7f9d2c86caf2",
      "date": "2019-12-09T17:02:46"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting. Can you please comment on your post where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis), you should contact teamsAppPerms@microsoft.com. This API requires special permissions so it isn't something the community can help with.

> To request access to these protected APIs, complete the following [request form](http://aka.ms/teamsgraph/requestaccess). We review access requests every Wednesday and deploy approvals every Friday. If you would like to provide information in addition to the form, you can contact teamsAppPerms@microsoft.com.

Comment: I had done these steps before and I still couldn't access the protected APIs. I had to contact someone on Microsoft side directly to have it unprotected, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the groupId instead of the teamId to get messages that worked for me.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + groupId + "/channels/" + encodeURIComponent(channelId)+"/messages?top=5
```

Comment: GroupId and TeamId is the same